Error in importing make_reduction for sktime. sktime and polars versions conflicting?
I'm trying to import make_reduction from sktime :
from sktime.forecasting.compose import make_reduction

but I receive the following error:
from polars import DataFrame
     80 
---> 81     pl_df = DataFrame({"__index__0": [0, 1, 2, 3], "a": [1, 4, 0.5, -3]}, strict=False)
     82 
     83     example_dict[("pl.DataFrame", "Series", 0)] = pl_df

TypeError: DataFrame.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'strict'

Gemini suggest a possible conflict between the versions of sktime and polars but its recommendation miserably failed in addressing the issue. Does someone experienced the same problem?
I simply tried to import make_reduction from sktime...

What versions of sktime and Polars are you using? I've added codeblocks - you may want to read the formatting page and refine the edit further. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

I think you are using an outdated polars version. I was able to reproduce your issue with polars version 0.20.2. Try upgrading to the latest version via: pip install polars==1.7.0 and your issue should be resolved.

Thanks a lot Ro.oT. That was the problem. With polars 1.7.0 everything is ok. Cheers
